# Kicked out when logged in?

Tags: login

When i log into ubuntu the screen goes black as it were logging in but then i am back in the login screen. I can login as guest (i should disable that). I can login via ssh. The last time i had no issues was when i used it this morning and the only unusual thing i did was shutdown via ssh (i think i wrote `shutdown now`) which had ubuntu hang after showing the shuting down screen for many seconds (i kind of assumed it shut down properly since the UI froze as well and it usually takes less time).

Whats the easiest way to fix this w/o reinstalling? Its a brand new install and so it probably takes me 10mins to recopy/setup everything so i may just do that

-edit- using 12.04

Comment: Take a look at the answers posted here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/189399/cannot-get-past-login-screen

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the file `~/.Xauthority`.

To do that,

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> at the login page.
- Enter your username and password, and you'd be able to login using `tty`.
- Now, delete the file:

```
sudo rm ~/.Xauthority
```

Comment: Excellent, that solved it perfectly (at least it seems to atm. i log in and see no problems)

Comment: glad it worked!