# ubuntu 14.10 not accepting my password

Tags: password, passwd

I've tried changing it from grub recovery mode and using root@username `mount -rw -o mount /` and typing `passwd username` and entering my new password but when I try to login with the new password the screen just flickers and returns to the logon screen. I haven't updated recently and yesterday it was working perfectly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kicked out when logged in?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/215608/kicked-out-when-logged-in)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a fault in the program itself,  I also have great problems with it.  That is why I am loading UBUNTU 14.04.1 again.

Comment: i also think it is a problem in Ubuntu 14.10 because I was able to create a new user and i am able to access all my files on the other account but what i don't get is that i am able to login into the locked account in shell but not in the graphical interface....