# Ubuntu 12.10 can not go past the login screen

Tags: 12.10, login-screen

I am using ubuntu 12.10 after installing iphone mount software I was asked to reboot. After rebooting my password was no more working.

I reset the password on recovery mode, now password works but every time I hit enter it keeps bringing me back to login screen.

I guess maybe an error on the last software I installed. How can I recover previous setting before the installation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/189399/cannot-get-past-login-screen

Answer (score 0):

Chek your  `~/.profile`, and see in last line. Maybe something wrong there, just comment it and try to reboot.