# Ubuntu 22.04 GNOME screenlocked and won't allow me to enter a password connecting via NICE DCV

Tags: gnome, lock-screen

I'm using NICE DCV to connect to my GNOME desktop GUI on Ubuntu 22.04. The connection seems fine, and I see the clock, and after a click, the lockscreen when I connect. But I'm not able to select the password field or type into it. If I hold my mouse over the password field, I see "Authentication Error" flash for a fraction of a second twice.

I tried disabling screen lock via ssh with this command both as root and my user with the same error:

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true

(process:26786): dconf-WARNING **: 11:25:02.720: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

Any suggestions how I can disable the screenlock from within an ssh connection?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this (my suggestion below) and am now waiting/hoping the problem with not being able to enter my password into the box after screensaver is gone for good.   I'm hopeful as I've read of others (in various versions of Ubuntu) who have achieved success doing this.   It makes sense to me too.

From the command prompt in your home directory, list all files including hidden files:

```
ls -lsagF
```

If your results include ANYTHING owned by root, change it to you (your user name) owing it.   This is often the case with .Xauthority which is often 'the' problem.

Error results looks like this (note root is the owner):

```
-rw-------  1 root       220 Feb  1 20:24  .Xauthority
```

It SHOULD look like this (if your username is 'fred'):

```
-rw-------  1 fred     220 Feb  1 19:41  .Xauthority
```

The fix (assuming your user name is "fred") is:

```
sudo chown fred:fred .Xauthority
```

Do the same with any other file or folder in your home directory.
Check again w/

```
ls -lsagF
```

until all are owned by you (the fix looks like this):

```
-rw-------  1 fred     220 Feb  1 19:41  .Xauthority
```

This MAY fix your inability to login after screensaver issue.
I'm still waiting to see if mine messes up again.

Open Disclosure:  This is NOT my fix - it was recommend by another; and now that I know what to search for, I see discussion on it being successful over the last 9 years in various versions of Ubuntu AND others.
This 2014 article in AskUbuntu discusses root NOT owning .Xauthority also.

[Why .Xauthority needs not to be owned by the root account in order to get past login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407275/why-xauthority-needs-not-to-be-owned-by-the-root-account-in-order-to-get-past-l)

I hope this is working for me now (fingers still crossed) and hope it works for you.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1281390)

Comment: Sorry, I kept adding my work around (plain txt from pluma text editor) to this problem but got a lot of (code?) before and after my text when I save.   I was unable (ignorant to howto delete process?) to delete so replaced it with the short msg above.