# Trying to change desktop environment but stuck on log in screen.

Tags: login-screen, desktop-environments

Im currently running lubuntu and was trying to try out gnome. now im in the log in screen and changed it to gnome in the top right hand corner. I proceed to  log in but the screen goes black and the lubuntu log in screen just appears again. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds similar: " http://askubuntu.com/questions/189399/cannot-get-past-login-screen " . Do you know how to get to tty screen? The answer on that page uses command line

Comment: No, that didn't work. I can still log into lxde and lubuntu just not gnome.

Comment: At this point I haven't much ideas and isn't exactly in freshest state of mind, so i apologize for sketchiness of my comment here. Have you tried reinstalling lubuntu desktop ? Also, you do know that you can have lxde desktop environment without having lubuntu , right? You could get rid of full lubuntu desktop and just desktop environment. Maybe try dpkg-reconfigure lxdm , and select lightdm as your default desktop manager. Alternatively , uninstall lubuntu-desktop, reinstall ubuntu-desktop, and just download lxde, which you then can choose on login screen.