# Login screen loop

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, login, guest-session

I have Ubuntu 12.04 64bits and it worked fine until today. This is the problem: when I introduce my password at the login screen a black window appears and then it comes back to the same screen. If I start as a guest everything works fine, but I can't log in with my normal account.

I tried the following with no luck:

[Installing GDM and/or reinstalling lightdm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130387/stuck-at-login-screen)

[Trying to remove the .Xauthority file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146137/login-screen-loops-unless-you-login-as-guest)

[Changing .Xauthority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-12-10-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

I can login through a virtual terminal (ctrl+alt+F1) without a problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it reinstalling my graphics drivers.

[How to install latest Nvidia Drivers](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/10/install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu.html)