# Can't login into GUI-- Boot as guest --login loop

Tags: 12.04, gui, login-screen

I hope somebody can help me with this frustrating problem. 
I'm running ubuntu 12.04, when I start my PC, it boots me into the login screen as guest. When I try to login, I always return as guest into the login screen. After pushing the login in button a few times I get a black screen with a white cross.

So I started to search the internet for a solution for my problem. Where I found a lot of threats where they said you should remove you .Xauthority. I followed this and rebooted my machine. After reboot I still have the same issue.

Is there anybody who can give me some support. 
(I'm not a ubuntu specialist)

Kind regards,
TMJJ

Comment: Hey there, has this ever worked? Also, what's the make and model of the GPU? This could be a driver issue. Nvidia is a common problem child.

Comment: Hi, it worked for 1 year. I allready updated the nvidia driver. I followed the following threat https://askubuntu.com/questions/266680/login-screen-loop?rq=1 without good result