# cant log into ubuntu as main/only user but can as guest

Tags: login

Up graded to ubuntu 13.10.  all ok then installed updates and afterwards trying to log in as usual just produced a loop of repeated login screens, but logging in as guest worked ok.

I think the problems may have been exacerbated by changing some permissions in my home directory.  I have read these forums but i am unclear about how to execute some of the replies and concerned about making things worse.
I can open a terminal ok. I have tried XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/home/myuser/.config. pressed enter but nothing happens. cursor just flashes.

please explain how to use the terminal to log in and any codes I can try to get my normal login back.  thanks

Comment: Your issue may be this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/146137/login-screen-loops-unless-you-login-as-guest. The most upvoted answer should work. It makes a backup of `.Xauthority`, so you could restore the old file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do the steps I take on solving my login problem, here, on my answer to other question:
[Solve login problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423725/ubuntu-12-04-32bit-cant-login/439472#439472)