# Ubuntu 12.04 32bit cant login

Tags: login

I have tried almost every comment in this subject.
my `.xsession-errors` file says:

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
```

and that is all. I can login as a guest but not with my account.

Comment: Checked .Xauthority, the permissions are as it should be.
Also deleted .Xauthority and .ICEauthority, did not work.
All packages are up-to-date. Please help.. there should be an easy way to restore my desktop. I should not move my files and delete my account. I wait for your comments

Answer (score 6):

After some days with this issue and many SO threads read, I found that this seems to be an Ubuntu open Bug (Status 'Incomplete' as of July 2015).

More information about it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1285444

The quick solution seems to be to rename the file that stores `dconf` settings:

```
$ mv ~/.config/dconf/user{,.old}
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete both `.Xauthority` and `.ICEauthority` from your user's home directory.

If you see old or backup or appended versions of either of these (for example `.ICEauthority-c`, `ICEauthority`, or `.Xauthority.old`) delete those too.

(Not having any of these files will not harm your system. They will be recreated at reboot/login.) After this, just reboot or logout & log back in and enjoy your computer again.

Tested on my system (Xubuntu 14.04 x86, linux kernel 3.13.0-35-generic)

Comment: removing the .ICEauthority file fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem, cannot login to ubuntu 14.04, but now I have succeed to login ^_^. This problem also have happened to older Ubuntu version, where I get to know the solution.
In my case there was a mismatch on desktop config from the user I login and the available desktop config. Here what i did:
([username] just as a placeholder)

First I check the lightdm.log:

```
-----------------------------------
sudo nano /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
---------------------------------------
I had a suspicion on these lines:
 ..................
    [+27.41s] DEBUG: Session pid=1114: User [username] authorized
    [+27.42s] DEBUG: Session pid=1114: Greeter requests session ubuntu
    [+27.42s] DEBUG: Seat: Failed to find session configuration ubuntu
    [+27.42s] DEBUG: Seat: Can't find session 'ubuntu'
..................
```

why did lightdm look for "ubuntu" session? 
This was because of [username] which i use its xsession is ubuntu. 
It was on /var/lib/AccountsService/users/[username]:

```
---------------------------------------
[User]
Language=en_US
FormatsLocale=id_ID.UTF-8
XSession=ubuntu <=====================  THIS ONE
Background=/home/[username]/Pictures/Wallpapers/1781785_10201241375132193_1896210726_o.jpg
SystemAccount=false

[InputSource0]
xkb=us
---------------------------------------
```

Then i look at the xsession in folder /usr/share/xsessions. 
There was only gnome.desktop, no ubuntu.desktop.

So that I changed the content of /var/lib/AccountsService/users/[username]:

```
from XSession=ubuntu to XSession=gnome
```

Problem solved ^_^

Comment: I had to install "ubuntu-session" to be able to login again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 13.04.

I rewrote the gnome.desktop entry in `/usr/share/xsessions` because it was missing:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GNOME
Comment=This session logs you into GNOME
Exec=gnome-session --session=gnome
TryExec=gnome-shell
Icon=
Type=Application
X-LightDM-DesktopName=GNOME
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
```

Then I removed gnome-session-* and reinstall all. Afterwards everything worked fine and I could choose the session I wanted, unity, gnome and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today, I noticed that some files and directories in the users home directory were owned by root, in particular .ICEAuthority, (this was most likely as a result of me trying to setup VNC). Anyway, once I used chown to change the ownership of these files back to the user I was able to login correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled Krita from source & had to modify the .profile to include the nonstandard install directory. I did it badly apparently. Once I corrected the syntax I could login as expected again!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score -2):

My problem was solved by turn off auto login.