# Login loop after installing Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, login

I keep getting a login loop (e.g. trying to login just redirects back to the login screen despite correct password.) This started occurring after trying to install Nvidia drivers using a .run.

During this installation, everything seemed to be okay except an error that pre-installation files could not be installed although I did not worry about this.

I have tried many things to try to rectify the situation after reading several other posts on here and other forums but none of this seemed to have worked. I have tried: removing and purging all Nvidia files and reinstalling Ubuntu desktop, reinstalling lightdm, changing permissions on .Xauthority, removing xorg.conf amongst other minor things but none of these have had any effect.

As I said, I'm aware of other posts on this but none of those solutions have worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide links to solutions that you have tried? This will help us know where to start because we are most likely going to start here.- >http://askubuntu.com/questions/590561/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-problem or here ->http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: Please list the type of nvidia card you have  to ensure you install the correct driver version.

Answer (score 2):

Install the NVIDIA drivers in a different way.
I assume you have a GEFORCE 400 or newer.

Step 1 : Remove the currently installed NVIDIA software.

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
```

Step 2 : Install NVIDIA drivers from Ubuntu repositories.

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

Now adding a boot parameter is not necessary anymore.