# Ubuntu 14.04 Login Loop and no WiFi

Tags: 14.04, login

Stuck in a login loop. Everytime I input my password, the screen flashes to a black screen for a second then back to the lock screen. Essentially its as if nothing happened.

I'm suspecting the issue might be related to a new video card. I recently upgraded to a GTX1060.

To make things worse, I can't connect to wifi from the lock screen either. I get an error

```
Failed to add/activate connection (32) Insufficient privileges
```

It doesn't matter the network, this happens always.

Comment: What happens if you try to log into the Guest account, or the root account (if you have that enabled)? Cheers, Al

Comment: I tried making other accounts as suggested here: http://askubuntu.com/a/607333/510652 but that did not solve the problem. I still could not get past the lock screen.

Comment: What kind of cards are they? Brand/model #? What happens if you pull out the "new" video card and reinstall the original "old" card? Cheers, Al