# Login Loop ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login, lightdm, login-screen

My Ubuntu 14.04 is stuck when trying to login my desktop. The screen goes black and soon after that the login screen comes back.

I've tried   [ubuntu 14.04 login loop problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590561/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-problem) and [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

But they didn't work. Then I `cat .xsession-errors`.

It show me following message.

```
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: gnome-session (Unity) main process (26961) terminate with status 1
init: unity-setting-daemon main process (26949) killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_unity-tweak-tool.1000.crash) main preocess (26870) killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_ibus_ibus-ui-gtk3.1000.crash) main preocess (26873) killed by TERM signal
init: xsession-init main process (26939) killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-release main process (26890) killed by TERM signal
init: hub main process (26953) killed by TERM signal
init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
init: indicator-bluetooth main process (27025) killed by TERM signal
init: indicator-printers main process (27037) killed by TERM signal
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Press CTRL+ALT+F1, type your username and password, then type `ls -lah` if the ".Xauthority" file reads like this:

> -rw-------  1 root root .Xauthority

Then do:

```
sudo chmod 777 .Xauthority
sudo chown username:username .Xauthority
```

Then restart lightdm by doing:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

This should hopefully fix your problem. If you have installed nvidia drivers and rebooted and this problem appeared, then tell me and I'll try to help you fix this problem.

Comment: I've tried this before :(

Comment: Do you have an nvidia driver? And what graphics card do you have?

Answer (score 0):

On the logon screen, open tty1 by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>.

Logon with your username and password.

Then run this command:

```
sudo rm .Xauthority
sudo reboot
```

Then try logging in.

Comment: I've tried this before, too :(

Comment: @user3927463 - If you have an Nvidia GPU, please try reinstalling the Nvidia drivers. You did install them through `apt-get`, right?