# mokutil startup screen

Tags: 14.04, boot, uefi

Due to problems with login loops I tried the following fix on my pc that required mokutil:

```
sudo mokutil --disable-validate
```

The fix didn't work, but it did add an extra startup screen to my boot sequence. Booting works fine, I can still reach GRUB and windows. But it is really annoying so I tried the following, to get rid of it:

```
sudo mokutil --enable-validate
```

This did not work. So my question is simple: how do I get my same old startup sequence back?

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought the solution for your original problem was here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/590561/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-problem

Comment: Haven't seen those solutions before. I'll check them out