# Stuck in a login loop and I already tried lots of things

Tags: xorg, login, login-screen

I am very new to Ubuntu. My Ubuntu 14.04 is stuck when trying to login my desktop. The screen goes black for a millisecond and soon after that the login screen comes back.

I tried most of the solutions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) and in this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590561/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-problem); however, nothing seems to work.

When the screen goes black for a millisecond I was able to capture this screen

[image: text in console before prompt returns]

**Edit:**
After installing xfce, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjzV6.png) are the drivers I have

**Solution**
Using nouveau xorg driver worked for me and I was able to login through both xfcx and the default sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have access to the login screen, try changing the session. Also if you want to run `startx`, try running it like so : `startx -- :2`. You may try another number if it doesn't work once.

After you log in, try finding any error log files. If you want to send them through command line, you may use : `cat ~/.xsession-errors | curl -F 'sprunge=<-' http://sprunge.us` and send us the resulting url.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59468/discussion-on-answer-by-daemon-stuck-in-a-login-loop-and-i-already-tried-lots-of).