# Ubuntu 17.04 why chrome-remote loops back ubuntu default dekstop environment?

Tags: login

I have installed Ubuntu 17.04. For a while it worked great. Then I have installed a couple of packages which I don't remember. When I rebooted my laptop, I couldn't login from the default login desktop environment. Every time I try to login, it accepts the password, but loopsback to login screen again. But from the Unity8 desktop environment I can login without a problem. its not a startx, lightdm,owner problem etc..

Comment: See this https://askubuntu.com/questions/590561/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-problem

Answer (score 1):

I have found out one reason for loop login: I had installed Chrome Remote Desktop to my laptop. I uninstalled Chrome Remote Desktop, and that solved the problem. Now I can log in to both desktop type Ubuntu Default and Unity8 without any problem.

To uninstall Chrome Remote Desktop:

1. Go to a terminal from the login screen with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. Enter the command: `sudo apt-get autoremove chrome-remote-desktop`.
3. Reboot the system.

Comment: I had the same problem. Uninstalling chrome remote desktop solved it.

Comment: Use anydesk remote app instead of chrome-remote. Anydesk is compatible with Ubuntu, windows, and android