# 18.04 Crashes After Installation

Tags: dual-boot, crash

The other month I needed to set up a dual-boot for Ubuntu and Windows 10. I have a separate 500GB SSD for Ubuntu. Originally, I had mounted an ISO onto a flash drive with 18.04.3 LTS and everything seemed to be working fine. I was was installing ROS and MATLAB onto the drive and after installing CrazyS Rotor Simulation and MATLAB I had noticed that the when I would go to login, the screen would become pretty unresponsive almost like I was running out of memory (i.e. inputs for mouse keyboard would freeze intermittently) and when I would open certain programs like Spyder or the help application, I would crash back to the login screen. This continued to happen every time I would try to open those programs, so I figured something had messed up with the install and I went and wiped my drive and installed clean again.

Now I've tried this a few times now and I keep running into the same issues, and I've noticed it happens when I update Ubuntu after being prompted that there's an update after install. So I went and got an ISO for the latest 18.04.4 LTS version. When I try to install with that version now, once everything is setup and I try to login, I immediately get crashed back to the login screen.
I've been limiting my installs to Google Chrome, ROS Melodic, MATLAB 2019b, Discord, Anaconda Python, and the updates needed to CrazyS (https://github.com/gsilano/CrazyS). Since I'm fairly new, I've just been following the tutorials on the websites for installing the software.

I'm not really sure what the issue would be, it was seemingly working originally when I installed the first time but now I keep having issues even when installing clean with the new ISO.

One thing I did notice is that there's another partition on the drive with Ubuntu that I don't remember making so it shows a P1 partition, ubuntu 1, and ubuntu 2.

I've been installing the third party drivers for my graphics card and everything else. My current setup is using a GTX 1080, GIGABYTE Z170X-Gaming G1, 16 GB RAM, a Skylake i7 processor, and then a s\Samsung 500 GB SSD  for Ubuntu (the Windows 10 is on a separate 250 GB SSD).

I'm pretty new to using this kind of setup on my personal machine so I'm not really sure where to look for debugging what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ubuntu 14.04 login loop problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590561/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-problem)

Comment: There are MANY possible causes of a desktop crash to the login screen. Look for the crash file in /var/crash to see what the system choked upon. Warning: the .crash file may be highly technical. You have multiple red flags: Older OS (18.04), third-party graphics drivers, and lots of non-Ubuntu software. Suggestion: Try a newer release of Ubuntu without the third-party graphics. If you have a separate /home and forgot to mention it, backup your data and wipe it.

Comment: So I just tried the 3 solutions in that link and none of them seemed to work. I'm constrained to using the older version for my class for ROS, so I can't switch to a newer version.  How would you view the crash file in Ubuntu? I was doing ctrl+alt+f3 to bring up the command line.

Comment: At this point, I think I might just try switching over to using VM. I was able to set it up on a VM with no issue. Could there potentially be an issue with how the memory is allocated? When I went through the clean installs, I just let it default partition my drive rather than manually allocate like I did the first install I did.