# Can't get into desktop after messing with input method settings

Tags: xubuntu, ibus, input-method, fcitx

I wanted to use fcitx as the input method framework in Xubuntu desktop and made the changes using im-config. After the change I restarted X Server and can't get into desktop. I tried rebooting, switching back to previous input method (ibus) which is chosen automatically, using alternative desktop environments (I have also Ubuntu unity and Lubuntu installed), nothing worked. Can someone give me some ideas as to where to check and how to fix this? I really don't want to re-install this box (it's a VM).

Comment: .xsessionerrors file says:

Comment: .xsessionerrors file says:
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
However nothing described in:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/423725/ubuntu-12-04-32bit-cant-login
worked for me.

Comment: Exactly what did you do when you "made the changes using im-config"?

Comment: Yes. I ran it several times. First time I chose "auto" because it was the recommended option. It chose IBus, which is not what I wanted. So I ran it again manually choosing "fcitx". I couldn't turn my IME on so I restarted the system. That was when I could not enter desktop. I switched to console by Ctrl+Alt+F1 and ran im-config for another several times in text mode, choosing "auto" (which ended up with IBUS) and IBUS, however nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal use, you should never need to call im-config manually in the first place. Switching between IBus and fcitx is best done using *Language Support*.

Anyway, you did. If you are reasonably sure that the problem is caused by your "messing" with IM settings, I'd suggest these steps:

1. Open a console window with Ctrl+Alt+F1 and log in.
2. Run these commands:

   ```
   rm .xinputrc
   sudo apt-get purge im-config
   sudo apt-get install im-config
   sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
   sudo reboot
   ```

Please note that purging im-config will likely result in the removal of a bunch of other packages. You need to accept that. Re-installing xubuntu-desktop should put those packages (at least most of them) back in place.

Comment: It worked! I was even ready to do a recovery reinstallation. Thank you su much Gunnar!

Comment: @Max: Very glad to hear that. To be honest, I wasn't quite sure it would help you.

Comment: it doesn't work if im on ubuntu and do `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` for that last command?

Comment: @user2167582: What is it that doesn't work? Please note that my answer was in response to the specific situation as described in the question.