# Locked out, but correct password

Tags: 14.04, password, lock-screen

I started up this morning, only to find my password is not working and I am locked out. When I enter the correct password, or when I try to login as a guest, the screen resets and goes back to the same login screen. In normal usage, I have disabled the lock screen, so I have no idea why it is occurring.

I can access my system via tty1. What can I do to remove the lock screen? I have tried several other threads, including changing the password via grub (no help). Thanks.

Comment: Whatever is the last action you did - you need to undo it.

Comment: Most probally its a problem with Xorg. what's the permisiion of .xauthority file present in your user folder

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/735056/520297 Hope it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem two weeks ago.

Press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and type in your username and password, then execute:

```
sudo rm .Xauthority
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and type in your username and password, then check for errors at .xsession-errors.old
May be you could get some information there

Or try installing other user interface to fix the problem