# Ubuntu failed to log in to UI

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I have a Ubuntu running on a virtual box. I cannot log into the UI with the valid username and password. It just shows black screen and returns to the login page again. Meanwhile the Guest Session is working fine.
What can I do to solve the problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question http://askubuntu.com/questions/146137/login-screen-loops-unless-you-login-as-guest

Comment: Definitely a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it sounds like you ran startx as root, which screwed with permissions on one or more files.

You'll need to get to a text console by pressing a key combination such as: Ctrl + Alt + F1 (any F1-F6 key will work). Next, log in as yourself.

Please check ownership on these two files:

```
    ls -l ~/.{ICE,X}authority
```

My guess is that at least one is owned by root, and not you. Change this:

```
    sudo chown user:user ~/.Xauthority (substitute user for your username).
```

Then reboot with:

```
    sudo shutdown -r now .
```

That should fix the issue for you. Here's more info on [xauthority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_authorization).

Comment: they are all owned by my username. And I cant see my virtual hard drive.

Comment: Zoinks. Sorry my suggestion barked up the wrong tree. Any updates?

Comment: It's okay. I would gladly accept any suggestion and try everything out. I haven't solved the problem but I will not use that Ubuntu anymore. I have backed up the important files using the installation disk and created another virtual machine. Anyway thank you!

Comment: @PriskaAprilia there are a number of questions of a similar sort on this forum. I'd hate to steer you in the wrong direction, but please let us know when you find an answer. I believe that you can accept your own answer once you do!

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your cache directory

```
mv ~/.cache ~/.cache.old
```

If it's not working, it can be compiz, so move .compiz folder too.

```
mv ~/.compiz ~/.compiz.old
```