# VirtualBox (Guest Ubuntu) login loop

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

First of all, I know there has been **a lot** of threads about Ubuntu login loops. I have read them and I feel like I've tried everything they proposed but nothing works.

## Background

I have VirtualBox installed with an Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits VM. I've had it for a while now, using it almost everyday. I've never had any problem with it. Two days ago, I installed a VirtualBox update and the latest Guest Additions. After installing the Guest Additions, I found that I couldn't mount my shared folder anymore, so I restarted the VM, tried again, and it still didn't work. I reinstalled the Guest Additions, restarted the VM, and then I could mount the shared folder just fine. However, I had lost the copy and paste function between my host (Windows 10) and my guest (Ubuntu). At the end of the day, I turned off the VM. The next day, I was stuck in a login loop (with my usual session and with the guest session). Before going back to the login page, I have a black screen that says:

```
* Starting LightDM Display Manager [OK]
* Stopping Send an event to indicate plymouth is up [OK]
```

## What I tried

### Checking virtualization

First, I checked the `.xsession-errors` file which indicated something about virtualization maybe being disabled and something about at-spi2-core. I didn't think of making a copy of this file and I deleted it since. I tried restarting several times since then and it stays empty now. Anyway, I checked that 3D Acceleration was still activated in the VM setting (it was) and that virtualization was still activated in the BIOS (it was).

### Checking Guest Additions

I then tried reinstalling the Guest Additions using the following code :

```
# Insert Guest Additions
mkdir /tmp/cd
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /tmp/cd
sudo /tmp/cd/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

The installation went normal, but it didn't help the login loop.

### Checking permissions

Following some threads about login loops, I checked permissions in `/tmp` ; `/home/myusername` and `/home/.Xauthority`. Everything was fine.

### Checking disk space

I also checked that my disk space wasn't full (even though it wouldn't have made sense since autocompletion worked) using `df -h` ; I still had 15 Gb of free space.

### Checking updates

I also tried updating using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` but there was nothing to update.

### Checking lightdm

I also tried some code found on other threads regarding login loops and lightdm :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
sudo service lightdm restart
sudo reboot
```

It didn't help.

### Checking random stuff found on login loops threads cause I really need my VM to work

Didn't help:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall at-spi2-core
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Didn't work (but not sure it should work since I'm on a VM):

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove fglrx*
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install fglrx # didn't work
```

Checked that I didn't have Xenial or other packages mixed with Trusty packages (using `apt-cache`): I don't, they all seem to be Trusty packages.

I also tried adding a new user with sudo priviledges but I also can't login to the new user, I'm still in a login loop.

## EDIT: Additional information

I don't know if this is relevant at all, but I made a new VM with a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits. I installed the Guest Additions, and each time I log into the VM, I have the following error message: `VBoxClient: VBoxClient (seamless): failed to start. Stage: Setting guest IRQ filter mask    Error: VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR.`
The only things I did on this VM are installing updates & Guest Additions. I enabled the copy/paste function between host and guest but it doesn't work either.

## My question

I ran out of options to help my login loop. I feel like I've tried everything I read on my Google searches. Does anyone have any input or idea about what I could try to make it work ?

Comment: No I haven't made any snapshot. I won't be caught making this mistake again.

Comment: Several suggestions: simply deleting `.Xauthority` helped me some time ago: https://askubuntu.com/a/147565/3940. Did you try this? What is your VBox version, perhaps needs another upgrade? Can you boot to an older kernel of Ubuntu? Is the guest session also affected?

Comment: @Takkat : I tried deleting `.Xauthority`, it didn't help. My VBox version is the latest, actually my problem occured after upgrading to the latest version of VBox. I cannot boot to an older kernel since I didn't make any snapshot (if there is another way I would love to be made aware of it). The Guest session is affected. Any new session I create is also affected.

Comment: Hold Shift key while booting should give you a menu to select previous kernels.

Comment: Ok, I really learned something here. I can boot to a recent kernel, however each time I boot have a "sorry ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error" or "system program problem detected" along with "vboxclient: the virtualbox kernel service is not running". If I try anything related to Guest Additions, I go back to the login loop on restart. Should I boot to an even older kernel ?

Comment: Looks like recent kernel patches conflict with the guest additions but I have no further information on that. *Suggestion:* create another VM to install and then update 16.04 and see if that performs better. If yes, you can attach your old 14.04 VDI to that new machine, mount it and then copy your data over. Should not take too much time, really. If 16.04 is not ok you can always go back to your 14.04. VM, it will still be there.

Comment: i updated vbox today on my win7 host. i ran into the same problem with lubuntu x64 16.04. Better not to update to 5.2.6 yet. In my VBox-Settings i had 3D Acceleration turned on too. After turning it off, i was able to boot. Before doing so i downloaded and installed the Guest Additions inside my VM during Recovery mode from this page: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.6/ Don't know if both in conjunction fixed it.

Comment: After turning off 3D Acceleration, I was able to login as well. Thank you!

Comment: Upvoted for a very nicely laid out question. Props to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if you are running with Virtualbox Guest Additions 5.2.6. That version is buggy and causes login infinite loops like that ones you have experienced.

> Important: The Guest Additions which come with VirtualBox 5.2.6 and 5.1.32 do not work properly on Linux guests with 3D enabled. Here are updated versions for 5.2.6 and 5.1.32.

Update for version 5.2.7 worked for me.

See https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17463

Comment: I didn't think of checking directly the Vbox tickets and I didn't see this issue while I was googling my problem! I guess I was using the wrong keywords. Anyways, updating to 5.2.7 worked for me too. It's nice to enjoy 3D Acceleration again :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Indeed the virtualbox landing page is messy. It is not that easy to see that notice. In the ticket there are some claims about.

Answer (score 2):

Just turn off the 3D Acceleration option of Virtual Box !!
Then I can login too.
Thank you very much.