# Unable to open anything other than terminal in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, firefox, nautilus

I cannot open any directory such as **Home** in Ubuntu. I found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371911/files-file-manager-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04) and tried it. I received errors as follows
[image]

In the terminal there is only one $ sign. No username is there. That was weird to me.

Another error is as follows
[image]

Also, I was not able to open browsers on Ubuntu 20.04. If I try to open Firefox I receive a popup message "Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible."

Lastly, the operating system freeze several times.

Can anyone let me know what's wrong with the operating system?

Comment: For the first issue, it looks like you may have set your user's home directory to (usually unreadable) /root - please [edit] your question to include the output of `getent passwd "$(id -u)"`. The second error seems unrelated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Comment: Why did you start Nautilus with sudo?

Comment: @nobody I don't know. I just tried to find a solution so that I can open the home directory. I am not able to open any directory or browser from the Ubuntu setup. Also, the machine froze if I tried to open the Home directory by clicking on with 4/5 times.

Comment: @steeldriver The output of the command you suggested is "myusername:x:1008:1009::/home/myusername:/bin/sh"

Comment: Please correct permission in home https://askubuntu.com/questions/140652/12-04-desktop-login-loop#144841

Comment: @nobody If I getting you right you ask me to use **sudo chown -R user:user /home/user** command. I did that and getting an error **chown: cannot access '/home/myusername': No such file or directory**

Comment: @Encipher ah sorry I realize now that the error message about `/root` was just because you invoked nautilus with sudo - please ignore my previous comment. However it is concerning if your home directory does not exist (or perhaps exists on a separate filesystem, that is not getting mounted?)

Comment: @steeldriver If home does not exist, what can I do?

Comment: @Encipher idk - tbh it's hard to understand how you managed to log in to a GUI desktop session with a non-existent home directory - unless you logged in and **then** moved or deleted it somehow?

Comment: Is this a fresh Install? Something is not right.